# portable library with Xamarin - .NET Standard vs. UWP

Tags: .net, xamarin, uwp

I have the following situation:

- Assembly X is a Xamarin class library I'm building. It is targeted to iOS, Android, and .NET Standard 2.0.
- Assembly X references the portability APIs in Xamarin.Essentials.
- Xamarin.Essentials is targeted to iOS, Android, .NET Standard, and UWP (`uap10.0.16299`).
- Now, someone wants to build a Windows 10 app using Assembly X.
- Since they're in Windows 10, I would like them to get the UWP version of Xamarin.Essentials. But it looks to me like it always pulls in the .NET Standard version instead, presumably because that's what X uses. The result is that they don't get the Windows-specific behavior that Xamarin.Essentials would provide.

Is there any way around this? Or do I have to build a UWP version of X as well? The reason I've avoided doing so up till now is that then I'll have some targets that I can only build on Windows, and others that I can only build on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that you have to **build** your custom `.NetStd` assembly in some way that is  platform specific. You compile **against** the Xamarin.Essentials .NetStd reference assembly and then you **bundle/include** the platform-specific of the Xamarin.Essentials assembly that includes the code that is platform dependent.

Thus at **runtime** the types in your custom `.NetStd` assembly will be forwarded/call into the `Xamarin.Essentials` platform-specific assembly that has been included in your app.

So in your custom `.NetStd` assembly that includes `Xamarin.Essentials`, there will be an external assembly definition:

```
.assembly extern Xamarin.Essentials
{
  .ver 1:0:0:0
}
```

And then in that same `.NetStd` assembly will be your code that calls to a type that exists in the assembly, ie: `OpenAppPackageFileAsync`

```
IL_0030:  call [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<[System.IO]System.IO.Stream> [Xamarin.Essentials]Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem::OpenAppPackageFileAsync(string)
```

Note: In the case of Essentials, it does not use DI/Interfaces to call the platform dependent code, the method `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` calls the `PlatformOpenAppPackageFileAsync` method and it is that method that will include platform-specific code in each of its platform dependent assemblies. In its .NetStd-based reference Assembly method, it throws a `NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException` as there is no general/generic .NetStd-based framework code that implements loading read-only app bundled Android/iOS/UWP files, ie:

```
.method private hidebysig static [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<[System.IO]System.IO.Stream>
          PlatformOpenAppPackageFileAsync(string filename) cil managed
  {
    // Code size       6 (0x6)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  newobj     instance void Xamarin.Essentials.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException::.ctor()
    IL_0005:  throw
  } // end of method FileSystem::PlatformOpenAppPackageFileAsync
```

Now when you package/bundle your platform dependent application, say Android in this example, you will not process/include the Essentials reference assembly, but the platform specific version.

The Android version of the `Xamarin.Essentials.dll` assembly includes this for the the `PlatformOpenAppPackageFileAsync` method:

```
.method private hidebysig static [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<[mscorlib]System.IO.Stream>
          PlatformOpenAppPackageFileAsync(string filename) cil managed
  {
    // Code size       70 (0x46)
    .maxstack  3
    .locals init ([mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<[mscorlib]System.IO.Stream> V_0,
             [Mono.Android]Java.IO.FileNotFoundException V_1)
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  brtrue.s   IL_000e
    ~~~~
    .try
    {
      IL_001d:  call       [Mono.Android]Android.Content.Context Xamarin.Essentials.Platform::get_AppContext()
      IL_0022:  callvirt   instance [Mono.Android]Android.Content.Res.AssetManager [Mono.Android]Android.Content.Context::get_Assets()
      IL_0027:  ldarg.0
      IL_0028:  callvirt   instance [mscorlib]System.IO.Stream [Mono.Android]Android.Content.Res.AssetManager::Open(string)
      IL_002d:  call       [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::FromResult<[mscorlib]System.IO.Stream>(!!0)
      IL_0032:  stloc.0
      IL_0033:  leave.s    IL_0044
      ~~~
```

Comment: I'm not able to follow the bytecode in your examples, but do I understand correctly that the answer is basically this: explicitly include `Xamarin.Essentials` in the host application, rather than just relying on the transitive dependency on it from my class library?

Comment: @E.Bishop Correct, each host application has to include/bundle the "special" platform-dependent version of the assembly that "matches" the reference assembly (.assembly Name/Version/Types included/...) that you compiled the the .NetStd library that contains your user-code against

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, this doesn't work in practice. After having added the Xamarin.Essentials package directly to my host app, it seems like it is still getting the .NET Standard code from Xamarin.Essentials when it's called from the class library - as evidenced by still getting NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException.

Comment: @E.Bishop What is the host app platform?

Comment: Oh wait... I thought this was a UWP project, but actually it was .NET 4.6. I'll try again with UWP.

Comment: Well, now I'm seeing a different problem: it is not letting me add my NuGet package at all in a UWP project. It complains that the package is not compatible with uap10.0.15063. The package has targets of netstandard1.4, netstandard1.6, netstandard2.0, and net45; shouldn't one of those be interoperable with UWP?

Comment: @E.Bishop UWP and NetStandard 2.0 on Windows 10 Fall Creators Update and above